# Camera plugin on Windows Phone creates square images

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm using the [camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) in my Cordova app. The **targetWidth** and **targetHeight** can be used to resize the image but, contrary to what [the documentation says](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameracameraoptions--object), it does not maintain the aspect ratio. Specifying a target width and height of 800 pixels should ensure that one side of image is 800px and the other is calculated based on that and the aspect ratio. However, this isn't the case - it just creates a square image of 800 x 800.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? It's looks like it's been an [issue for a while](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4027) but it clearly hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution although it's a it of a hack.

1) In your Windows Phone project, open **www/plugins/cordova-plugin-camera/src/CameraProxy.js**

2) Find the **resizeImage** method and add the following:

```
function resizeImage(successCallback, errorCallback, file, targetWidth, targetHeight, encodingType) {

    ...
    image.onload = function() {
            var imageWidth = targetWidth,
                imageHeight = targetHeight;
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var storageFileName;

            /* ====== INSERT THIS CODE ==== */

            // Maintain aspect ratio (make sure image size is no bigger than target width/height).
            if (image.width < image.height) {
                var aspectRatio = image.width / image.height;
                imageWidth = imageHeight * aspectRatio;
            }
            else {
                var aspectRatio = image.width / image.height;
                imageHeight = imageWidth / aspectRatio;
            }
            /* ====== END OF CODE ADDITION ==== */

            canvas.width = imageWidth;
            canvas.height = imageHeight;
```

> Note: this change will get lost every time you re-build the app. You
>   can change **plugins/cordova-plugin-camera/windows/CameraProxy.js** to fix
>   this, however, this might cause issues with upgrades as Cordova might
>   not be able to update the file given that is has been modified.